# Transparent window losing focus makes keyboard events not working

Tags: python, winapi, pygame, mouseevent, keyboard-events

I have a transparent window. If you press `m` it turns translucent and if you press `esc` turns transparent again. The thing is that this mechanism works if you haven't clicked the mouse. Once you click it, this mechanism stops working. My intuition is that when i mouse click, the window loses focus and stops reading events. I don't know how to make it to ignore mouse clicks and keep reading events.

Should I use maybe a keyboard/mouse listener? (not familiar with that)

```py
pygame.init()

info = pygame.display.Info()
w = info.current_w
h = info.current_h
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((w, h), pygame.NOFRAME) # For borderless, use pygame.NOFRAME
done = False
fuchsia = (255, 0, 128)  # Transparency color
dark_red = (255, 0, 0)

# Create layered window
hwnd = pygame.display.get_wm_info()["window"]
win32gui.SetWindowLong(hwnd, win32con.GWL_EXSTYLE,
                       win32gui.GetWindowLong(hwnd, win32con.GWL_EXSTYLE) | win32con.WS_EX_LAYERED)
# NOTE: Transparent
win32gui.SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hwnd, win32api.RGB(*fuchsia), 0, win32con.LWA_COLORKEY) 
# NOTE: Translucent
#win32gui.SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hwnd, win32api.RGB(*fuchsia), 50, win32con.LWA_ALPHA)


transparent = True
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_q:
                done = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                # NOTE: Turn screen transparent
                transparent = True
                fuchsia = (255, 0, 128)
                win32gui.SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hwnd, win32api.RGB(*fuchsia), 0, win32con.LWA_COLORKEY) # NOTE: Transparent
            if event.key == pygame.K_m:
                # NOTE: Turn screen translucent
                transparent = False
                win32gui.SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hwnd, win32api.RGB(*fuchsia), 65, win32con.LWA_ALPHA) # NOTE: Translucent
                show_text()

    if transparent:
        screen.fill(fuchsia)  # Transparent background
    else:
        screen.fill((255, 255, 255))  # Translucent background

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)


pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Keyboard input goes to the foreground window. When you click "on" a transparent window, the mouse click goes right through that window, and makes the window underneath the foreground window (which will now receive keyboard input). If you need to observe keyboard input regardless of whether your window is the foreground window, you'll need to use lower-level input processing infrastructure (like [Raw Input](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/raw-input)).

Comment: @IInspectable This is more of an answer than a comment.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Feel free to use that information to write up an answer.

Comment: [Register a system-wide hotkey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registerhotkey), which works even when you don't have keyboard focus.

Answer (score 0):

Keyboard input goes to the foreground window. When you click "on" a transparent window, the mouse click goes right through that window, and makes the window underneath the foreground window (which will now receive keyboard input). If you need to observe keyboard input regardless of whether your window is the foreground window, you'll need to use lower-level input processing infrastructure (like [Raw Input](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/raw-input)).